# I'm trying to pull a control parameter for a sql datasource from a dropdown but it's not being recognized

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have 2 sql datasources. What's supposed to happen is the following: On page load, the first sql datasource pulls a list of 'desknames' and populates a dropdown. It should default to the first deskname but I added some c# code behind to select the first item by index on pageload just to be safe. Then a second sql datasource should load, using the selected 'deskname' as a control parameter. From the second sql datasource I populate an html table with labels that are populated in the code behind from the datasource. I've tested the second datasource-html table when I manually put in the control parameter, and it works fine.

All I can think of is that somehow the deskname in the dropdown is not being selected in time to be passed as a parameter to the second sql datasource, but I don't know how to fix it. I've tried playing around with the order that things appear in the code, but it hasn't made a difference. By the way I'm using asp.net webforms with c#

Here is my code:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hiddenUserID" runat="server" Value="" />

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="Desknames" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:spvConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="exec pmtv2.spTOOL_Deskdropdown @username">
    <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hiddenUserID" Name="username" PropertyName="value" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>

<div id="topdiv" style="float:left; padding-left:2.5%; width:30%; border-bottom:0px; height:20%;">    
     <h2>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="ChooseDesk" runat="server" DataSourceID="Desknames" 
             DataTextField="Deskname" DataValueField="Deskname" AutoPostBack="true"  class="dropdown" OnDataBound="ChooseDesk_databound">
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </h2>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="DeskSummary" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:spvConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="exec pmtv2.spTOOL_LandingPageDesk @username, @Deskname">

     <SelectParameters>
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="hiddenUserID" Name="username" PropertyName="value" />
    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChooseDesk" Name="Deskname" PropertyName="SelectedValue" DefaultValue="Laundry & Tobacco"/>
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Notice I have defaultvalue="laundry & tobacco", this is just a temp fix that allows the second sql datasource to populate but normally I won't be able to hard code in a default value like this.

This might be a tricky one, but any suggestions on why this is not working would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change your `SeletCommand` to

```
SelectCommand="spTOOL_LandingPageDesk"
```

and add the following attribute

```
SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure"
```

if your parameters are already defined in your stored procedure you don't have to declare them again by using the `exec` call.

I'm assuming your pmtv2 is the user you are using to log into the database. You don't need that as the connection string in the web.config has already taken care of this for you.

Also, I noticed your using class in your drop down's attributes. Set that to CssClass. It may be contributing to your problem.

```
class="dropdown"
```

should be:

```
CssClass="dropdown"
```

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me. pmtv2 is actually a schema name for the stored procedure. I tried the changes you suggested, but Im still getting the same error - Object reference not set to an instance of an object (which I only get when the sql database is not being fed the right parameter and therefore its output is not seen as a valid object)

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered that you need to initialize the control.  I would recommend using an OnInit event and an OnSelecting in the datasource.  In these functions I would set your control values.